# Excel VBA - Expressão Dentro de Evaluate, retorna valor errado

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel

Boa noite a todos.
Estou fazendo um sistema com navegação através de UserForms (sem a planilha de fundo).
Monto uma ListBox com base em um filtro de datas comparando as datas em células da planilha com critérios escolhidos pelo usuário: [Campo Data - ComboBox], [Operador - ComboBox <=; >=; =] e [Data - TextBox].
Estou utilizando a função **EVALUATE**, para avaliar minha condição e observando passo a passo, percebo uma "inconsistência"
Resultados
"19/01/2022 <= 20/01/2022", Retorna VERDADEIRO - OK
"21/01/2022 <= 20/01/2022", Retorna FALSO - OK
**"21/02/2022 <= 20/01/2022", Retorna VERDADEIRO - N OK**

A primeira data, busco na planilha:
*CDate(Cells(i, CInt(mCriterios(j, 0))))*
*mCritério(j,**0**)* guarda a coluna referente ao campo na planilha.

O operador "<=" busco através de um ComboBox selecionado pelo usuário:
*Me.cbb_tipodata.List(Me.cbb_tipodata.ListIndex, 1)*

A Data, de um textbox digitado pelo usuário:
CDate(Me.ttb_dataacoes.Value)

*[código]

*mCriterios(j,**1**) = Me.cbb_operador.Value & CDate(Me.ttb_dataacoes.Value)*

On Error Resume Next

operador = CDate(Cells(i, CInt(mCriterios(j, **0**)))) & mCriterios(j, **1**)

operador = Evaluate(operador) 


If Not operador Then

GoTo DESCONSIDERE

End If*

Alguém entende o motivo do erro e teria uma solução? (estranhamente, com datas dentro do mesmo mês, funciona, as demais a função Evaluate retorna VERDADEIRO, ainda que o resultado seja FALSO).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para que fique o Resgistro consegui resolver levando para dentro do EVALUATE Variáveis com valores numéricos das referidas datas.

Para todas as datas a serem comparadas, coloquei a função CLng (...).

Assim, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Para conseguir o correto retorno de comparação das datas encapsulei todos os POSSÍVEIS testes numa Function, que retorna True ou False. Adapte o código para que passe cada um dos três parâmetros (a data 'da esquerda', o operador de comparação, e a data 'da direita'):

### Adaptação:

```
If Not fnReturnTFDates(CDate(Cells(i, CInt(mCriterios(j, 0)))), _
    Me.cbb_tipodata.List(Me.cbb_tipodata.ListIndex, 1), _
    CDate(Me.ttb_dataacoes.Value)) Then
    GoTo DESCONSIDERE
End If
```

### Função:

```
Function fnReturnTFDates(ByVal strDateEsq As String, _
    ByVal strOperador As String, _
    ByVal strDateDir As String) As Boolean
    
    Select Case strOperador
        Case "="
            fnReturnTFDates = CDate(strDateEsq) = CDate(strDateDir)
        Case "<>"
            fnReturnTFDates = CDate(strDateEsq) <> CDate(strDateDir)
        Case "<"
            fnReturnTFDates = CDate(strDateEsq) < CDate(strDateDir)
        Case "<="
            fnReturnTFDates = CDate(strDateEsq) <= CDate(strDateDir)
        Case ">="
            fnReturnTFDates = CDate(strDateEsq) >= CDate(strDateDir)
        Case ">"
            fnReturnTFDates = CDate(strDateEsq) > CDate(strDateDir)
        Case Else
            Stop 'parece que o operador está inconsistente.
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Alex, grato pela consideração e acredito que funcione. confesso que não queria "apelar" para Select Case já que o próprio operador está no campo de escolha.